# Data visualization tools for geographic data project

Tags: python, visualization

I'm pretty new to the whole idea of data visualization, so I was hoping people could point me in the direction of efficient tools to use for a problem I have:

I've got a lot of numerical data (they are counts) that are tied to specific countries with a two-letter country code. Ideally, I'd like to be able to represent these counts using a sort of world heat map. In other words, if the count for India is 20 and the count for China is 5, I'd want China to be colored light red and India to be colored dark red.

What tools would be best to do something like this? I do my data manipulation and analysis using pandas and Python, so I'd love to keep things in the Python family, but I'd love any suggestions at all.

Comment: The type of plot you want is commonly called a chloropleth map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Matplotlib has something called [basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/)
2. [Vincent](https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent)

Answer (score 3):

[Databench](https://github.com/svenkreiss/databench) is a tool that connects your Python analysis with an html frontend where you can use tables and interactive elements to navigate your data. You can also use d3.js or higher level JavaScript libraries that use d3.js to visualize your counts on a map.

Comment: D3 is a wonderful library.  dc.js, build on D3 and Crossfilter, is also worth looking at.

Comment: Wow, how have I never come across Databench before! It looks amazing. Definitely want to play with it at some point.